# what does load_instruction_at_checked() return? the data before processed or post-processed?

Tags: solana-program

At first sight, we can infer that `load_instruction_at_checked()` return the raw/input instruction from client, but bellow example from official doc not work as we expected.

https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/secp256k1_instruction/index.html#example-verifying-multiple-signatures-in-one-instruction

The question is, what are `load_instruction_at_checked()` return? Bellow are possible case.

1. is load_instruction_at_checked() return the the raw/input instruction from client? If yes, then how can there are sign result in the secp256k1 instruction that end user build, submit?
2. if case 1) not hit , then what does load_instruction_at_checked() return? From the official example, load_instruction_at_checked() return data that contain secp256k1 sign result. Obviously, it is the data that have be modified by secp256k1 instruction, base on the raw/input instruction.

So, with bellow diagram,  does load_instruction_at_checked() return IX'' in all case?

```
┌────────────────────────────────┐               
│                                │               
│    Input/Raw Instruction Data  │           IX' 
│                                │               
└───────────────┬────────────────┘               
                │                                
             runtime/processor                       
                │                                
                ▼                                
┌─────────────────────────────────┐              
│                                 │              
│Post-processed Instruction data  │          IX''
│                                 │              
└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

the document should be more detail on `load_instruction_at_checked`, on what does it return.

This bring another question:  Will all instructions modified IX data after executed? or only secp256k1/ed25519 instruction can modify the instruction data?

Maybe there document on how IX data read, process, how/when the IX data be modified, I wonder.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the intent is to enable the ix to be modified. For example, one area where we use `load_instruction_at_checked` or `get_instruction_relative` is to introspect the ix list to see if we are within a CPI

```
/// Panics if the top-level relative instruction is not our program
pub fn validate_not_cpi(sysvar: &AccountInfo) {
    let our_key = &Pubkey::from_str(OUR_KEY).unwrap();
    let index_relative_to_current: i64 = 0;
    let instruction_sysvar_account_info = sysvar;
    let current_ix =
        get_instruction_relative(index_relative_to_current, instruction_sysvar_account_info)
            .unwrap();
    if &current_ix.program_id != our_key {
        panic!("This ix is not permitted within a CPI");
    }
}
```

But if you're really curious how the data is packed you can read it. The first 8 bytes are the function hash/identifier e.g., `ix.data[0..8]` and the rest of the slice is the args. Note that the hash is equivalent to:

```
pub fn get_function_hash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);
    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()[..8],
    );
    sighash
}
```

where namespace is probably "global" and the name is your function name as it appears in regular snake case.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have the same idea that runtime normally not modified the data inside IX struct. But it totally up to runtime who can reconstruction IX data that `load_instruction_at_checked ` returned  to archive some goals . Obviously secp256k1/ed25519 instruction are the ones on the special list.